# automatic labels to prometheus alertmanager rules

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm using [prometheus-community/prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus) chart

I'd like to add the following labels automatically to any alert manager rule firing

- env=**prod**
- cluster=**project-prod-eks**

so that I don't these labels manually to each alert rule.

```yaml
 - alert: NGINXTooMany400s
   expr: 100 * ( sum( nginx_ingress_controller_requests{status=~"4.+"} ) / sum(nginx_ingress_controller_requests) ) > 5
   for: 1m
   labels:
     severity: warning
     env: prod
     cluster: project-prod-eks              <---------------HOW to inject them?
   annotations:
     description: Too many 4XXs
     summary: More than 5% of all requests returned 4XX, this requires your attention
```

so that I can do something like

```
 - alert: NGINXTooMany400s
   expr: 100 * ( sum( nginx_ingress_controller_requests{status=~"4.+"} ) / sum(nginx_ingress_controller_requests) ) > 5
   for: 1m
   labels:
     severity: warning
   annotations:
     description: Too many 4XXs on {{ $labels.env }} / {{ $labels.cluster }}  <----- THIS
     summary: More than 5% of all requests returned 4XX, this requires your attention
```

#### Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `external_labels` to your [prometheus.yml](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/):

```yaml
global:
  # The labels to add to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
    env: prod
    cluster: project-prod-eks
```

The community chart has it in [values.yml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/values.yaml#L1345):

```yaml
serverFiles:
  prometheus.yml:
    global:
      external_labels:
        foo: bar
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

so I did slightly differently that modifying the "serverFiles", see below

```yaml
server:
  nodeSelector: 
    prometheus: "true"
  baseURL: "https://prometheus.project.io"
  enabled: true
  retention: "30d"
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  global:
    scrape_interval: 30s
    external_labels:
      env: prod
      client: client-name
      project: project-name
      cluster: project-prod-eks
```